# 部分テンプレートにまとめた画像を、トップページ以外でも表示できるようにしたい

Tags: ruby, html

ヘッダーにまとめた画像を、どのページに遷移しても表示できるようにしたい。

RubyでWebアプリケーションを作成しています。
部分テンプレートを用いて_header.html.erbを作成してところ、トップページを離れると画像が表示されません。
ブラウザ上のエラーは出ていません。

例.ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/css/style.css"):

同様のエラーがターミナル上で画像数分確認されます。

各viewでは `<%= render "shared/header" %>` で部分テンプレートを呼び出しています。

よろしく願いします。

#### 該当のソースコード

_header.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<div class="title">
<% if user_signed_in?%>
  <h2><%= link_to current_user.nickname %></h2>
  <%= link_to "ログアウト", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <h2></h2>
  <%= link_to "新規登録", new_user_registration_path %>
  <%= link_to "ログイン", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
</div>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>今日のトレーニング</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/ress.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/style.js"></script>

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="assets/png" href="assets/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>
<header>    
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-12">
    <div class="head">
        <h1><%= link_to "training diary", root_path %></h1>
        <div class="snsbox">
            <img src="assets/in-icon.png" alt="Instagram">
            <img src="assets/fb-icon.png" alt="Facebook"></div>
        </div>
    </div></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-12">
        <nav>
            <div id="open"></div>
            <div id="close"></div>   
            <div id="navi">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "ホーム", root_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "今日のトレーニング", new_main_path %></li>


            </ul>
                </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: トップページとトップページ以外ページで違いはなにかありますか？例えばURLの階層がちがう等

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
階層が違っていると思っています。コントローラー名mains_controllerを使用していますが、ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/mains/assets/run.jpeg"):
のように、aseetsの前にmainsが出てきます。
ここがaseets/run.jpegになれば、エラー解消できると思っているのですが,,,

Answer (score 1):

imgのsrcが相対パスを指定されているので、トップページと子の階層ページではアクセス先が変わります

以下の例の場合

```
<img src="assets/in-icon.png" alt="Instagram">
```

`http://example.com` の場合
=> `http://example.com/assets/in-icon.png` にアクセス

`http://example.com/mains` の場合
=> `http://example.com/mains/assets/in-icon.png` にアクセス

となり、アクセス先が変わります

先頭にスラッシュをつけて絶対パスとしてください。トップパスからのアクセスとなります

```
<img src="/assets/in-icon.png" alt="Instagram">
<img src="/assets/fb-icon.png" alt="Facebook">
```

Comment: スラッシュを付けたところエラーが解消されました！
絶対パスと相対パスの関係性について再度学習していきます。
ご教授いただきありがとうございました！